# angular project structure, Services & Controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Earlier today I asked about how to call one controller from another, I was having a lot of trouble with what functions should be where etc. This got me thinking on the bigger picture, on how I should build my project, to be as clean and logical as possible.

My application works against a SharePoint server, I have service.js files with `$resource` factorys to communicate with SharePoint, an example:

ItemService.js

```
myApp.service('ItemService', function ($q, Item) {

    this.getItem = function (id){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        setTimeout(function() {
            var item = Item.get({ID: id }, function(){
                deferred.resolve(item.d.results[0]);
            }, function(error){
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
        }, 1000);
        return deferred.promise;
    };

});

myApp.factory('Item', function($resource) {
    return $resource("serverURL/lists/getByTitle('Items')/items", {}, {
        get: {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            url: "serverURL/lists/getByTitle('Items')/items?$select=&$filter=ID eq :ID"
        }
    });
});
```

To use these services I have a controller file, example:

ItemController.js

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('ItemController', function ($scope, $modal, $log, ItemService) {

    $scope.loadItem = function(id){
        var promise = ItemService.getItem(id);
        promise.then(function(item){
            $scope.viewItem(item);
        }, function(err){console.log(err);})
    };

});
```

This was example of the controller and service files for the sharepoint list `Items`, I also have one controller and one service for `Tasks`, as well as the main controller, `AppController`.

Are my extra controllers unnecessary? Should I just inject my services into my AppController, and write my function there instead?

My problem is that when my project gets bigger, this way is easier to read and understand, but code gets more complicated since controllers would have to communicate a lot. On the other hand, if I inject my Services into my AppController it would be hard to read, but still work as intended.

Comment: You can check this: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#application-structure

Comment: @Xlander reading it right now, seems very helpful, but my question is specifically on the usage of services & controllers, still, I should try and follow his guidelines

Comment: I would suggest to write all controllers and services separately for readability (even if the project gets bigger). It will be an advantage for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to keep my controllers responsible for a single thing.

For example, I have a project management app. On the project page there is a search on the left side and the selected project on the right. I have a controller for each because they are unrelated enough that I can change one without affecting the other.

The selected project display has three tabs, one for general info, one for a list of tasks and another for a list of contacts. I have a controller for each tab. Because they all inject the project service they all have access to the same project object when they instantiate, and this keeps each controller focused.

When the user adds a task or a contact I display a modal with a list of available tasks or contacts. A separate controller handles that list and modal.

It's the single responsibility principle and it works well to keep your code clean, even if it means having a few more controllers. It also means my stuff is reusable. If I want to have one of those modals on a different entity I can, because the modal has no concept of the project, it only knows it's doing a search for tasks or projects and returning the selected ones to its caller. If I had one big controller for everything I would have to write that code again.

Comment: I'm gonna try and write some controllers this way, so instead of having one controller for the whole Task object, I would have one for each crud operation, i.e viewTaskController, editTaskController etc..

Comment: Sure, that works if you have different views for viewing the Task object and editing it and if they have different behaviors. But you don't have to split controllers up by CRUD operation. My ProjectController handles both retrieving and updating the Project object (well, the ProjectService handles the request but the controller initiates the request) because I display the Project in an editable view all the time (my "edit" page and "view" page are the same).

Comment: yeah I understand. I have different views for each operation (well, not delete but..), For my project as it is now this works great, I have plans to build it further, so will see if this approach works then also

Answer (score 1):

If your app is growing, do break it out into multiple controllers. In my last project in public/js/media folder, I had media.js (the controller), media.service.js, media.tmpl.html and _media.scss.

A simpler way is to break them up by main views (you may have nested views or templates as well).

As far as injecting services go, I like to do as much work as possible in the service and I restrict the actual service to dealing with external data and the factory deals with local/returned data being passed around, parsed or replicated.

I structure my API calls the way you've done with just attaching a promise on the end of the API call from the service. This will keep your controllers much cleaner as your code expands.

Comment: +1 - This is very similar to the approach that our team has settled on after a couple of large angular projects.  Each main area of the app has it's own subfolder, with it's own config (ui-router), service (external data), factories (local/returned data), controller, and another sub-folder that has the main view and partial templates.  It works quite well for us.